# How does p-value play into classification model outcome?

Tags: machine-learning, p-value, random-forest

I've created a classification model that predicts whether a design will succeed or fail. It returns the probability of success, rather than the actual classification label (e.g. 0.68 instead of 1). My supervisor has asked me to add a "Recommended action" panel, which tells the user whether their design has good chances of succeeding or if they need to revise the design, based on the output of the model. He has asked that the cut-off for revise/proceed should be statistically significant and use p-value to do so. I'm not sure how to calculate p-value here, since I don't know what the null hypothesis should be. Is it an appropriate use of the metric?

Comment: Is your supervisor a statistician? It sounds to me like he is more confused than you are.

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes, he is a biostatistician

Comment: Then I guess I am confused, but I don't understand. Can you ask him to clarify?

Comment: While you get clarification from your supervisor about what's expected, could you please edit the question to add more details about the "designs" you are evaluating and how "success" is estimated? Usually it's best to start with the estimated probability of an outcome and choose the probability cutoff for classification based on the relative costs/benefits of different false/true classifications. It's not clear how to apply that principle here, based on what you've written so far.